# Inequalities on Matrix Minimax?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, inequality

Suppose I have a matrix $M$. How can I get a good bound on the minimax quantity
$$
\min_{i}\max_{j}M_{ij}
$$
or variations thereof? Links to literature would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I understand now that this question is too general as stated to have a useful answer. When you know more about where your matrix is coming from, spectral methods seem to be the way to go.